# c# Make a delayer but still be able to have form open

Tags: c#

and on my c# program whenever i try:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(#);
```

## as in delay number

It works, but whenever its "delaying" (i guess that's what its called) I can't get my form to pop up on my screen from the task bar, almost like reopening it (?). Could somebody help me make a thread that doesn't "freeze" the form? Thanks!
So, yeah, I have already tried

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(#);
```

But that just freezes the form :/ thank you
oh btw, this is c#

Comment: Please post a code snippet, showing where the `Thread.Sleep` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to delay a operation.

Example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
timer.Start();
```

After 10000 MS the following Method will be called:

```
   private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //DoSomething
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after a background worker.  This will allow you to keep your main form up but do some time consuming processing on another thread.  Since you didn't post any specific code for your issue, I'm pasting in a snippet from a larger example found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress(i * 10);
            }
        }
    }
```